# TypeScript error Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express.js, request

Como posso solucionar o erro

```
Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>
```

Criei uma pasta @types na raiz, dentro dela tinha um arquivo `express.d.ts` com o seguinte código

```
declare namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      user: {
        id: string;
      };
    }
  }
```

quando digito request. já me dá a opção request.user porém quando vou rodar o código da erro justo nessa linha.

Answer (score 4):

Olá, como não foi mencionado eu presuponho que você esteja usando uma versão mais recente do Typescript, se este é o caso o problema pode ser resolvido da seguinte forma:

```
- raiz
  - @types
    - express
      - index.d.ts
```

Acima é só uma sugestão sobre como organizar as pastas e não deve influenciar a funcionalidade do código abaixo:

```
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request{
            user: { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

A versão acima é testada e funciona com a versão 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, tive o mesmo problema que você, pesquisando aqui eu achei a solução:
no tsconfig.json use isto:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "./src/@types",
  "./custom_typings",
  "./@types",
  "./node_modules/@types"
]
```

na raiz do seu projeto crie uma pasta chamada custom_typings, dentro dela crie uma pasta chamada express, dentro da pasta express crie o index.d.ts e insira o seguinte codigo:

```
declare namespace Express {
  interface Request {
    user: {
      id: string;
    };
  }
}
```

salve e rode o projeto.. Já era!

Comment: Ñ entendi pq votaram negativo... sua resposta funciona (tanto faz botar numa pasta express ou não) e mostrou explicitamente o objeto por dentro. Funcionou com TS = ou > 4.0 e VS code. Detalhe, na raiz do projeto apenas se Babel ou Webpack transpilar lá; no meu caso tudo subfolder de src...

Answer (score -1):

Crie um arquivo `.d.ts` e adicione o seguinte código:

```
import * as http from 'http';

declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
  export interface Request extends http.IncomingMessage, Express.Request {
    userId: number;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

No seu package.json em scripts deixe da seguinte maneira:
`"dev": "ts-node-dev --inspect --transpile-only --ignore-watch node_modules src/server.ts"`

Answer (score -2):

Eu estava fazendo o bootcamp igual a você, parece pela pergunta,

Foram 2 passos simples.

1- Dentro do tsConfig.json eu adicionei:

```
"typeRoots": [
        "./src/@types",
        "./node_modules/@types"
      ]
```

2- Eu mudei a organização das pastas para ser @types/express e o arquivo dentro dele chamei de index.d.ts

Ai foi de boa :D
Boa sorte!